# Permission Set with license "Salesforce Integration" not permitting access to Opportunity object

Tags: integration, profile, permission-sets, licenses

This Permission Set (to be used by an API-only integration user) packaged in my 2GP as metadata is not granting access to the Opportunity object even though I explicitly enabled it...

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PermissionSet xmlns="https://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <label>My Custom Permission Set</label>
    <description>Assign to integration user.</description>
    <license>Salesforce Integration</license>
    <fieldPermissions>
        <field>Opportunity.My_Custom_Field__c</field>
        <editable>true</editable>
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
    <fieldPermissions>
        <field>Opportunity.Amount</field>
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
    <fieldPermissions>
        <field>Opportunity.Type</field>
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
    <objectPermissions>
        <object>Opportunity</object>
        <allowRead>true</allowRead>
        <allowEdit>true</allowEdit>
        <viewAllRecords>true</viewAllRecords>
    </objectPermissions>
    <hasActivationRequired>false</hasActivationRequired>
</PermissionSet>
```

Once deployed to a scratch org, the Permission Set does not list **Opportunities** in the list of objects under Object Settings.

If I change `<license>SalesforceAPIIntegrationPsl</license>`, I cannot deploy this metadata as part of the managed package.

The user I created has a **Salesforce Integration** User License which gets associated by setting the Profile to **Salesforce API Only System Integrations** Profile. My Permission Set specifies the object and fields I need to use. If the **Salesforce Integration** Permission Set license is not the correct one to use, what is the name of the one I should use (that can be packaged in a 2GP)?

Is there something about the **Salesforce API Only System Integrations** Profile that blocks access to Opportunity (even if a Permission Set tries to grant it)?

Comment: The Integration user license should be able to sufficient for what you're looking to achieve. In addition to assigning the custom permission set that grants access to Opportunity, have you also assigned the Salesforce API Integration Permission Set License to that integration user? This is required alongside assigning the Salesforce Integration license to the user.

Comment: Note: starting with Spring '24, `Salesforce API Only System Integration` profile is [deprecated](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_api_new_user_profile.htm&release=248&type=5).

Comment: It's a permission set license rather than a permission set. You can either assign this license to a custom Permission Set or add it under the Permission Set License assignment section of the user. In terms of the Profile, that's expected. You shouldn't be managing object or field permissions at a Profile level anyway and your approach of using a permission set to provide this access is the correct approach.